# How to enable lazy loading for Repository Items in ATG

Tags: repository, atg

I would like to know how one lazily loads repository items specified in ATG.  I have tried all the options as given in the ATG Repository Guide under [Lazy Loading Settings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1016lazyloadingsettings01.html) , but so far all the properties of an item configured to be lazily loaded are fetched along with the parent item.

For example if a User entity has one-to-many relationship with Organization,  loading a  user repository item results in all the organization items for the user getting loaded along with its properties such as billing and shipping addresses.  This happens even if the organization collection is not used.

Any replies with some examples other than what is given in the repository guide or any gotchas would be great.

Comment: How have you been able to determine the item's properties are not being lazily loaded? In your specific example incidentally, I wouldn't fret over some additional user details such as user addresses being loaded; it's not that much data and in a commerce application you are likely (you hope) to need that information.

Comment: I have looked at the various properties that are accessed using the getProperty method of the RepositoryItem in the code under question.  Even when we are not explicitly accessing a property of a shipping address from an organization, I can see sql calls being made to the contact_info table when an organization is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When a property has **lazy loading** enabled, the property is **not** fetch from the database along with the repository item. The property would be loaded from the database (with another SQL query) when it is needed ie. the property displayed in a page or used in a component.

Couple of examples when it make sense to use lazy loading properties:

1. When a repository has properties (quite often with large content) which are not used that often it is good to enable lazy loading on them e.g. you may have a "News" repository item type with properties as follows: title, creation date, content (long string). If you present list of news items (only title) ordered by creation date, it make sense to load only title and creation date. Therefore content property should have lazy loading enabled. That property will be fetched when you visit a particular news item. You do not have to load all the content properties during news list presentation which will improve page display performance.
2. Another example (similar to the above) might be with product catalogue and product description property. Usually in a category page you present only product title along with image. Product description is loaded and presented only when a product page is displayed. It make sense to set up product description property as lazy loaded in order to improve performance of category (or subcategory) page.
3. It is also good practice to use lazy loading if a query returns a very large number of repository items and you use only a few of them most of the time. The ones which are not used (they do not have to contain large content) can be lazy loaded.

I have been using lazy loading properties in all my ATG projects and I think it is a great feature. However, you have to consider all pros and cons before applying it. Sometimes it may cause more harm than good.

I hope that will help you better understand lazy loading and enjoy working with that feature in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Order History in ATG is a great example of when lazy loading can be useful.  If you think about a typical use case for this it is along the lines of:

1. User views the order history page i.e. the list of all their past orders
2. Navigates through the results until they find the order(s) they are interested in viewing
3. Views an order or a small subset of the orders

Without lazy loading enabled ATG would load all the order objects for that particular user when viewing the summary of past orders.  The order object a very large and complicated object, and loading multiple orders consumes significant resources on the database and the application servers.

With lazy loading enabled when the user views the order history page, only the information which is needed to display the list of past orders is loaded, anything which is not needed directly by this page is not loaded.  If the user then clicks through to an individual order then any additional information is loaded at that point.